# how to display correct recurring profile price in cart in opencart 2.x

Tags: php, opencart, customization, opencart2.x

every time I add a subscription option to the (opencart) cart the price that gets added is the actual product price and not the subscription price. is there an easy fix for this?

**EDIT**
So I believe I was able to fix this issue. I took a look at the code in the \system\library\cart.php file (I'm currently using OC version 2.0.1.1) and edited lines 255 and 256

from this:
`'price' => ($price + $option_price),`
`'total' => ($price + $option_price) * $quantity,`

to this:
`'price' => ($price + $recurring['price'] + $option_price),`
`'total' => ($price + $recurring['price'] + $option_price) * $quantity,`

**EDIT #2**
So turns out the above edit doesn't fully solve the issue because it ends up double charging on checkout. I'm going to try to figure this one out when I have some time. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you give us the code you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover over the “Catalog” link in the nav bar you will see the new “Profiles” link in the drop down. This section is for creating the billing profiles which can be assigned to particular products later on. By setting it up this way, you can have an unlimited number of pricing subscriptions for your OpenCart stock and assign the ones you need.

Check this Link - http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/07/26/how-to-set-up-subscription-payments-in-opencart/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have already created a test profile that charges $10 every 2 weeks. However, when I add this subscription option to the cart from the product page the price in the cart shows $0 instead of the subscription price of $10. I'm assuming what's happening is that it's adding the actual product price (which I have set to $0) and not adding the subscription price. So I'm wondering if there's an easy fix for this issue.